# Unit Testing + Jasmine + Angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, resharper

i am getting all the time "encountered a declaration exception". I am trying to write my first unit test for a factory. It seems like mocking doesn't really work.

The paths to do references look like this:

```
///<reference path="~/App/js/jasmine/jasmine.js"/>
///<reference path="~/App/js/lib/40_Angular/angular.js"/>
///<reference path="~/App/js/jasmine/angular-mocks.js"/>

///<reference path="~/App/app.js"/>
///<reference path="~/App/services/userService.js"/>
```

My sample tests look like this:

```
describe("userService", function () {

 beforeEach(module("issApp"));

 describe("userService", function () {

 var userService;

 beforeEach(inject(function () {
  userService = $injector.get('userService');
 }));

 it('should be true', function () {
  expect(true).toBeDefined();
 });

 it('should have a farbSchema', function () {
  expect(userService.getParameter("ngFarbSchema")).toBeDefined();
 });
});
```

My app.js is declared like this:

```
iss.app = angular.module("issApp", ["ng", "ui.router" ...]);
```

userService.js is declared like this:

```
iss.app.factory("userService", function ($q, $http) {
 return {
    getParameter: getParameter,
    setParameter: setParameter,
    ...
 };
 function getParameter(parameterName) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http({
        url: iss.urls.base + iss.urls.getuserparam,
        method: "GET",
        params: { parameterName: parameterName }
    })
    .success(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function (error) {
        console.log("Fehler beim Aufruf userService.getParameter(): " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }
  ...
});
```

This are the version of the tools I use:

Resharper: 8.2.1

Angular: 1.5.8

Visual Studio: 2013

Jasmine: 2.4.1

Comment: i think it would be better you post the code of the factory...

Comment: Ok, i added some more code for the factory.

Answer (score 0):

```
expect(userService.getParameter("ngFarbSchema")).toBeDefined();
```

i dont think it is good to check if method is defined that way.
 better way is to check method without call it:

```
expect(userService.getParameter).toBeDefined();
```

look at this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4K5Yka?p=preview)

Comment: I know the check is useless (semantically). I just try to get my first unit test runned and evaluated by Resharper/VS 2013. It must be some kind of syntax or settings error.

Comment: You undersdtand me wrong,  i didnt say it useless, just you need to change the test and check property instead of calling it

Comment: Ok. I changed it, but i get still the same error. I am pretty sure, the test fails at this row: beforeEach(module("issApp"));

Comment: that strange, may be you have some error in your issApp module definition, may be you should try see if the app  running without tests?
another plunker  - http://plnkr.co/edit/ivCsQG?p=preview

Comment: The app is working. Maybe it is some referencing or router problem? I use ui-router for angular. I just open the test.spec.js in VS and then go to Resharper menu and start the unit test. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure vs and resharper nothing to do with issue you have.
More likely the problem caused by ui-router or some other dependency you didnt place corectly.
For check it - you may try to remove all the depenedencies from issApp module (only for see the tests start to run)
One more recommandation - try to run your tests only with jamine (create some index file with jasmine references) so you will see more info anout your error

Comment: you can also fork my plunker and change it to be private (if you afraid someone see you code) and try to place the full code of app